# How to configure domain account password expiry notification mail

Tags: email, powershell, active-directory

We have one common domain account for our application LDAP authentication purposes and now looking to set password expiry email notification for this single domain account. I m just a normal domain user. I don't have AD permissions. So is it possible to enable the remainder email configuration to send some of our team members?

Our local IT department informed that it is possible to notify to our common domain account's mail only(this mail box we don't check regularly).

Comment: Disable password expiry for that account. It's a bad idea generally, and particularly bad for a functional account.

Comment: I have discussed with our IT to disable password expiration, but they said as our domain policy every 60 days once need to change the password.

Comment: Bad policy, leading to bad solutions and bad security.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory does not have any sort of built-in password expiration email notification system. Anything that might exist within your organization is either a homegrown script or a 3rd party software package your IT admins have installed. So if your IT department says they can only notify the email address associated with the shared account, it's likely a limitation of that software or script.

But your personal domain account potentially has everything you need to write your own notification script. You only need read-access to user objects in AD which all users have by default unless your organization has modified the default permissions. You can query the details of the shared account and check the [msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f9e9b7e2-c7ac-4db6-ba38-71d9696981e9) attribute. Then based on the value, send your notification.

Comment: thanks ryan, do you have code for this action?

Comment: I have written code for such purposes in the past. But I have nothing current.

Comment: ok i will check it. thanks